# Coqui YourTTS Enhanced (additional voices) Model Deployment

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, text-to-speech, coqui

I am trying to deploy  the following trained (new voices cloned) multilingual YourTTS model:

[YourTTS Model with 60+ Voices from Huggingface](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqbFFCbllJbDZMMUZYVWlwZ1RIUGtaQ0QtOEZUZ3xBQ3Jtc0trU1hYbFN6Y1hmY1ZxQm54WUtpMVQ3U2ZVcnhBOGhFS2tMWTFrZllIOTl4QUs0MnRfZHNIYW9LeElYUjdWZlktcURxMGh0NlJvdm50QktYb1Bfakh6Nk11QXptTXVockFyZjRoZW9pdFItd29Vcjl2UQ&q=https%3A%2F%2Fhuggingface.co%2FAOLCDROM%2FYourTTS-Fr-En-De-Es&v=hr86Zd9Mni0)

The model is associated with the following YouTube video:

[Now for Download: YourTTS (English, French, German, Spanish) Multilingual Model with 60+ Voices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hr86Zd9Mni0&t=87s)

I am trying to run the model locally on my `WINDOWS` laptop. I am using the following command line prompt to run the model:

```
python synthesize.py --text "This is a test sentence." --out_path "C:/Users/Home/OneDrive/Projects/Projects/QuranBeheld/scripts/coqui_TTS/nanonomad_models/output.wav" --model_path "c:/Users/Home/Environments/quranbeheld3.10.11/Lib/site-packages/TTS/nanonomad_models/checkpoint_1978000.pth" --config_path "c:/Users/Home/Environments/quranbeheld3.10.11/Lib/site-packages/TTS/nanonomad_models/config.json" --speakers_file_path "C:/Users/Home/OneDrive/Projects/Projects/QuranBeheld/scripts/coqui_TTS/nanonomad_models/speaker_ids.json" --speaker_idx "VCTK_johnw"
```

As I was getting 'File Not Found' errors, so I had to modify the `config.json` file to make references to the appropriate files on my local system (can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12DBQDQqjCihOOOFFWwl-817PF78R5bUp?usp=sharing)). As I was still getting error (different ones) I then manually created the `speaker_ids.json` file (can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12DBQDQqjCihOOOFFWwl-817PF78R5bUp?usp=sharing)).

I am currently getting the error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Home\Environments\lib\site-packages\TTS\tts\utils\managers.py", line 194, in <setcomp>
speakers = sorted({x["name"] for x in embeddings.values()})
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

How may I to proceed to get this new model working?

Thanks.